# $f(x-a)+f(x-b)$ vs $f(x-a)f(x-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider the condition $f(x)=0$ if $x<c$ and now we wish to determine the values of $x$ for which :

1. $f(x-a)f(x-b)$ is equal to $0$, for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
2. $f(x-a)+f(x-b)$ is equal to $0$, for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Now I thought of it this way:

For $(1)$: if $x<c$ then we assign a new value of $x$ as $x\leftarrow x-a$ for $f(x-a)$ and $x\leftarrow x-b$ for $f(x-b)$ so we get $x-a<c$ **and** $x-b<c$ this would mean $x<a+c$ **and** $x<b+c$. Therefore, we have:
$$
(x<a+c)\cap(x<b+c)
$$
Therefore, $x<\min(a+c,b+c)$.

For $(2)$: Same thing, we get $x-a<c$ **or** $x-b<c$ this would mean $x<a+c$ **or** $x<b+c$. Therefore, we have:
$$
(x<a+c)\cup(x<b+c)
$$
Therefore, $x<\max(a+c,b+c)$.

> 1. Is my reasoning right?

> 2. Is this also true for negative real numbers?

Comment: This is wrong:
" if x<c then x−a<c "

Comment: Why? I am assigning the value of $x$ as $x-a$ in the form of $x\leftarrow x-a$ @jjagmath

Comment: That's not what is says. I can only judge what you write, not what you are thinking...

Comment: That could be used in programming, in Mathematics we don't have such notation.

Comment: If $x \geq c$, does this imply that $f(x) \neq 0$?  Also, for part 2, is anything known about those values of $x \geq c$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$?  If not, it seems like the only way to **guarantee** that equation (2) is satisfied, is if $(x-a)<c$ **and** $(x-b)<c.$  The problem with this inference in part (2) is that there may be **other** values for $a,b$ such that for **some** values of $x,~~$ $f(x-a) + f(x-b) = 0.$  How might these **other** values possibly be deduced without more information about the behavior of $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes if $x\geq c$ then indeed $f(x)\neq0$ also we can take for sake of simplicity an example with $a=1$ and $b=2$ and $c=-1$

Comment: For part 2, in your opinion, is it the problem composer's intent that only those values of $x$ that satisfy both $(x-a) < c$ and $(x-b)< c$ are to be considered?

Comment: yes as long as $x<c$ then $f(x)=0$ and if $x\geq c$ then $f(x)\neq0$. Therefore, we are trying to see here if by shifting the function by $a$ and $b$ and considering values like $a=1$ and $b=2$ and $c=-1$, we should see that $f(x-1)f(x-2)$ should yield $x-1<-1\implies x<0$ and $x-2<-1\implies x<1$ so essentially we have $x<0 \cap x<1$ so does this mean that the solution is $x<0$ or $x<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment/questions, it seems that you made a mistake in part 2.  If I am not mistaken, the constraint of

$$f(x-a)+f(x-b) = 0 \tag1$$

**must be** interpreted as

$$f(x-a) = 0 ~\textbf{and}~ f(x-b) = 0.\tag2$$

At least this is the impression that I got when I indicated that no other information is known about $f(x)$ except that

$$x < c \implies f(x) = 0. \tag3$$

This means, that in trying to **guarantee** that equation (1) above is satisfied, since the only information given is represented by equation (3) above, you are forced to interpret part 2 of the problem as requiring that constraint (2) above is satisfied.

This means that you must have:

$$(x-a) < c \implies x < (a+c) ~~~\textbf{and}~~~
(x-b) < c \implies x < (b+c).$$